# Is there a way to mock milvus database?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, mocking, milvus

I'm working on a project for semantic search using Transfomers + milvus (1.1.1) database.
Is there a way to mock milvus database, or run tests without having to create a milvus server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding currently, you may need to implement a mocked Milvus, and the test code for pymilvus-1.x is based on a real Milvus server. Maybe the code for pymilvus-2.x which on the master branch could be a good reference for implementing the mocked Milvus from scratch.

You could find the pymilvus's Mocked Milvus here:

https://github.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/blob/master/tests/mock_milvus.py